# Arduino and Visual Studio interfacing

Tags: usb, arduino

Hi friends I want to make when i press button who connected to arduino and when i press him to show it on visual studio smiley i write an code but the OvalShape1 is show only one time :X

Visual Studio code :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
Shared _continue As Boolean
Shared _serialPort As SerialPort

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles MyBase.Load
    SerialPort1.Close()
    SerialPort1.PortName = "com4" 'change com port to match your Arduino port
    SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
    SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
    SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
    SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One
    SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None
    SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default 'very important!
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
        SerialPort1.Open()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Dim dataRecive As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()

    If (dataRecive = 1) Then
        OvalShape1.Visible = True
    ElseIf (dataRecive = 0) Then
        OvalShape1.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Arduino Code :

```
int button = 7;
int buttonState = 0; 
int lastButtonState = 0;

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(button, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
buttonState = digitalRead(button);
if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
if (buttonState == HIGH) {
  Serial.println("1");
}
else {
  Serial.println("0");
}
}
lastButtonState = buttonState;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: i want to make visualization on visual studio with arduino. I want when i press button who connected to arduino and when i press the button to send data to usb serial port and with visual studio recive that data and show it on the screen :) example with an shape or image :)